# bind mount /proc in Docker container with user namespaces enabled

Tags: docker, namespaces, proc

My dockerd (CentOS7: 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6) is running with user namespaces enabled for better isolation.

Now I build a image which is supposed to read for monitoring purposes also from /proc of the kernel. Thus I tried to mount /proc onto /host/proc in the container

```
host> docker run --network=host --userns=host --pid=host --privileged -v /proc:/host/proc:ro --name mycontainer  my/container20180204
```

and bind-mount during container start-up over the containers proc namespace view

```
docker> mount -o bind /host/proc /proc
```

However, event with the user namespace of the host, the container's root process is apparently run within the dockerd's user namespace mapping, as the container's root cannot bind mount /proc

```
mount: only root can use "--options" option (effective UID is 100000)
```

Running as non-privileged user does not work, as it tries to mount it as real file system(?!?) from the layers

```
 /var/lib/docker/100000.100000/btrfs/subvolumes/${SHA256}/proc\\\\\\\" cannot be mounted because it is located inside \\\\\\\"/proc\\\\\\\"\\\"\"": unknown.
```

So, I fear that the user namespace limitations are for good and not bypassable...?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#user-namespace-known-limitations

Comment: This may be relevant to this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/897299/how-do-i-mount-a-private-proc-inside-a-namespace-inside-a-docker-container/897476#897476