# How do I mount a private /proc inside a namespace inside a docker container?

Tags: security, docker, namespaces

I have a need to create namespaces inside a Docker container. And as part of this, I will need to mount a `/proc` private to the inner namespace. I realize that I will have to run the container with certain privileges to make this happen, but I would prefer to enable the most minimal set.

This works:

```
$ sudo docker run --privileged --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined \
 -it fedora:rawhide /usr/bin/unshare -Ufmp -r \
 /bin/sh -c 'mount -t proc proc /proc'
```

This doesn't:

```
$ sudo docker run --cap-add=sys_admin --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined \
  -it fedora:rawhide /usr/bin/unshare -Ufmp -r \
   /bin/sh -c 'mount -t proc proc /proc'
mount: /proc: cannot mount proc read-only.
```

So, just turning off seccomp filters and adding `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` isn't enough. What *is* enough?

**Update:** Selinux is a part of the problem. If you turn off selinux enforcement globally, it works. But, you can also turn off enforcement for a particular container with `--security-opt label:disable`, and this is documented in the [security configuration section of the online Docker manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#security-configuration):

```
sudo docker run --cap-add=sys_admin --security-opt label:disable \
 -it fedora:rawhide /usr/bin/unshare -fmp /bin/sh -c \
 'mount --make-private / ; mount -t proc proc /proc'
```

But that fails if the `-U` and `-r` flags are added back to `unshare`. And, of course, adding `--privileged` to the docker run command works just fine even with the `-U` and `-r` flags.

I'm currently trying to use the kernel tracing stuff to figure out what, exactly, is giving me an EPERM. It's a very unhelpfully unspecific error to get.

Comment: SamYaple on the #docker channel on Freenode has been pretty helpful here, and this may be a cgroups issue. There appears to be a 'devices' cgroup.

Comment: have you tried using -v /proc:/proc ?

Comment: @c4f4t0r - Well, that wouldn't do what I want. I don't want the /proc from the namespace docker is running in (presumably the root level namespace).

Comment: @c4f4t0r - Using ftrace, the kernel sources and some creative thinking, I figured out the problem. https://serverfault.com/a/897476/71430

Comment: This won't help you, but TBH: I'm *really* surprised this isn't a standard `mount` option as it seems a pretty common requirement to me. I need it :) ... I'm running a single binary & including all its libraries, so there is no need for a base-O/S in the container - so I don't have one, but it does seem to want `/proc` for some features. The same would happen with static binaries, like `Go` ones - they could be installed without a base-O/S in a container. I tried `-v /proc:/proc` and it doesn't help for the reason you give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command works:

```
sudo docker run --cap-add=sys_admin --security-opt label:disable -it fedora:rawhide /bin/sh -c 'for dir in $(awk '"'"'/\/proc\// { print $5; }'"'"' /proc/1/mountinfo ); do umount "$dir"; done; /usr/bin/unshare -Ufmp -r /bin/sh -c '"'"'mount --make-private / ; mount -t proc proc /proc ; ls /proc'"'"
```

I didn't split it over multiple lines because the quoting is really important. Basically, it unmounts a whole bunch of stuff in `/proc` before running unshare and mounting `/proc` in the child user namespace.

Docker mounts over a bunch of directories and files in `/proc` with its own directories that are empty tmpfs directories and null files. Various files in `/proc` represent values that are applicable to the whole system. In fact, `/proc/kcore` would allow you to read kernel memory inside the container if you were root, which, since a lot of people want to believe that containers are some kind of lightweight VM or something, would surprise a lot of people.

The kernel in (as of version 4.14 anyway) `fs/namespace.c:mnt_already_visible` checks to see if you're mounting an already mounted filesystem, and if that filesystem has things mounted as child filesystems and those mounts have the MNT_LOCKED flag, it fails. The MNT_LOCKED flag seems to be applied (I didn't hunt down where this is in the kernel) to all mounts whenever you create a user namespace in order to prevent you from unmounting things in that namespace (because you get privileges 'within' the user namespace) and making hidden stuff visible again.

The command I posted uses an awk script on the contents of `/proc/1/mountinfo` to pull out all of the subdirectories of and files in `/proc` that Docker has mounted over, and unmounts them all. This makes the `/proc` filesystem mountable in nested user namespaces again.

Comment: It doesn't work. Please don't waste time of people with those replies.

Comment: @LtWorf - That isn't a helpful comment. This command worked for me. It's possible Docker has changed how it does things since I wrote this and so this doesn't work anymore. Or it's possible I missed some crucial piece of information necessary to its correct functioning. But I didn't post a 'useless reply' because I posted what I did to solve my problem. If you want to be helpful, please say why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Speaking of outdated information, Worf is a Lieutenant Commander, last I heard. :)